# FillMaxWidth does not take into account other elements in a Row - Jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Why the composable Icon does not appear?

*The Cardcontent composable is FillMaxWidth*

I want the "Cardcontent" composable to do fillMaxWidth inside the "Cardtest" composable taking into account the "Icon" composable

[image]

[image: this is the design]

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Icon () {
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icon),
        contentDescription ="Icon",
        modifier = Modifier.
        size(width = 40.dp,
            height = 40.dp) )
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun Cardcontent (){
    Row (horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth())
    {
        Avatar()
        TextDesc()
    }

}

@Preview
@Composable
fun CardTest(){
    Row(Modifier
            .width(310.dp)
            .padding(start = 16.dp)
            .padding(vertical = 13.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically)
    { 
        Cardcontent()
        Icon() 
 }
}
```

Comment: You mean Card content should take all the width available after placing the Icon in the row?

Comment: Add weight as 1f in the Card Content . When you create a reusable composable usually you want to pass the the modifier from the calling function that helps in reusing same Composable in multiple places with different sizes and arrangement . So add a argument  to Card Content  and set the weight as 1f..

Comment: Kindly add the code as text. For more info - [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with ADM opinion, you must pass the modifier as an argument of CardContent() and that's mandatory, because in order to asign a weight(1f) modifier to your CardContent component, the declaration must be within the scope of a Column or Row, because of possible reusability, you CardContent component could be used in a Box or scaffold in the future, and weight doesn't apply for this components, so imagine that having it declared inside of the CardContent as default weight and then placing it inside of those examples would be useless and give you a sintax error, so finally you must do something like this:

```
fun CardTest(){
   Row(
       Modifier
           .width(310.dp)
           .padding(start = 16.dp)
           .padding(vertical = 13.dp),
       verticalAlignment = Alignment.centerVertically
       )
       {
           Cardcontent(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
           Icon()
       }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but it didn't work exactly like this for me

I can't add the modifier weight to the cardcontent call from there, what I did was change the Cardcontent composable call to the code of the cardcontent composable and there I was able to add the Modifier weight argument.

This works exactly as I want but I lose the atomic design methodology that I want to use

Answer (score 0):

You should in CardContend insert argument wherein you hand over component Icon